# Is there a website providing LaTeX source files to guide beginners?

Tags: miktex

I am learning LaTeX by using the book ***More math into latex***. So I want to find some good LaTeX source files teaching the syntax. This way, I think I can master basic rules of LaTeX in a faster approach.

By the way, why does LaTeX not work on `tex.stackexchange.com`? It works in mathematics stackexchange. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can find some examples here: https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/examples/ (there are even some from the book you mentioned)

Comment: regarding why latex doesn't work the same way here as on the math site, see this question on the tex meta site: [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1272/579)

Comment: I can recommend [LaTeX for complete novices](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/novices/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

In my expirience, the best way to learn LaTeX (or any programming language for this matter) is to have concrete project to work at. So If you studding math, physics, computer science or anything of this kind, just start doing you homework, papers or anything in latex, and ask if you have questions. As it comes to resources: I don't know any page better than this. Just browse the (answered) questions to the topics that interest you, and you will learn a lot.